# Passing variable angular from component to another

Tags: angular

This is my app.compononent.html:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})

export class AppComponent {

isAuthenticated = true;
}
```

Is there a way to pass the isAuthenticated varaiable to my HeaderCompononent.ts ?

Something like this maybe: `<app-footer bind = isAuthenticated></app-footer>`

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Input(). @Input() allows a parent component to pass data in the child component.

app.header.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  template: `<h1>{{isAuthenticated}}</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class AppHeaderComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() isAuthenticated: boolean;
}
```

and use it in app.component.html

```
<app-header [isAuthenticated]="isAuthenticated"></app-header>
```

Comment: Thank you so mush for your time, sory could do you help to refactor my question ?

Comment: You wanted to pass isAuthenticated variable to my HeaderCompononent.ts. right.. Please tell me if you have any other question.. Happy to help you.